# joi problem with custom message with ref function

Tags: validation, ref, joi

```
confirmpassword: Joi.string().valid(Joi.ref('password')).required().strict().messages({
"string.valid": "Passwords do not match",
"string.required": "Confirm password is required"
})
```

how can i set a custom message for .valid(joi.ref('password'))
because this is not working
"string.valid": "Passwords do not match"

i just wanted whenever someone enter a diffrent password in confirm password the error
to be some this like this  "Passwords do not match"
not this "confirmpassword" must be [ref:password]

Answer (score 0):

If you check the validation's returned error.details, you'll see that the `type` is `any.only` and not `string.valid`.

```
{
   message: '"confirmpassword" must be [ref:password]',
   path: [ 'confirmpassword' ],
   type: 'any.only', // <- here is the type of the error
   context: {
      valids: [Array],
      label: 'confirmpassword',
      value: '1',
      key: 'confirmpassword'
}
```

}

So replacing that would fix the issue.

```
confirmpassword:  Joi.string().valid(Joi.ref('password')).required().strict().messages({
"any.only": "Passwords do not match",
"any.required": "Confirm password is required"
});
```